# How to make a python script executable in py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I downloaded py2exe for python 2.6. I include this bit of code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['move2.py'])
```

'move2.py' being my first script. This code is from my second script as said in the video. I opened cmd and typed 'movesetup.py py2exe' and pressed enter. Instead it came up with a error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\move.py", line 1, in (module)
    from distutlis.core import setup
ImportError: No module named distutlis.core
```

I downloaded py2exe right and I downloaded the right one for Python 2.6. Here is the website that I found how to change .py to .exe. Is he right? I also tried cx_freeze too but that didn't work either. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR483VkOvkE

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo: `distutlis`

Change to `distutils`, and read the error next time. ;)